# I am unable to create 2 views in H2 database, My script have 2 views but I see only one view is created. One view overwrites other view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, view, h2

## // First view

```
CREATE VIEW WEB_VOY_SEARCH_CT_DETAILS_VIEW
    AS
       WITH W1
            AS (SELECT TRIM (TD.WEB_ITIN_CODE) AS WEB_ITIN_CODE,
                       TRIM (TD.TOUR_ID) AS TOUR_ID,
                       TRIM (TD.VOYAGE_ID) AS VOYAGE_ID,
                       TD.DURATION AS TEMP_DURATION,
                       TD.TOUR_START_DATE,
                       TD.TOUR_END_DATE,
                       TRIM (ALT_TOUR_ID) AS ALT_TOUR_ID,
                       ALT_TOUR_START_DATE,
                       TD.ON_REQUEST_DAYS
                  FROM TTURDEPT TD),
            W2
            AS (SELECT W1.WEB_ITIN_CODE,
                       W1.TOUR_ID,
                       W1.VOYAGE_ID,
                       V.WEB_ITIN_CODE AS VOY_ITIN_CODE,
                       V.SHIPBOARD_CURRENCY,
                       V.VOYAGE_STATUS,
                       V.VOYAGE_ATTR,
                       V.PRODUCT_CODE,
                       V.DURATION,
                       (W1.TEMP_DURATION - V.DURATION) AS TOUR_DURATION,
                       V.DEPARTURE_DATE,
                       W1.TOUR_START_DATE AS CRUISE_START_DATE,
                       W1.TOUR_END_DATE AS CRUISE_END_DATE,
                       V.INCLUDE_EXCLUDE_FLAG,
                       TRIM (V.FROM_PORT) AS FROM_PORT,
                       TRIM (V.TO_PORT) AS TO_PORT,
                       V.SHIP_VERSION,
                       V.ZONE_DECK_FLAG,
                       TRIM (V.SHIP_CODE) AS SHIP_CODE,
                       W1.ALT_TOUR_ID,
                       W1.ALT_TOUR_START_DATE,
                       W1.ON_REQUEST_DAYS,
                       TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL1) AS TOUR_UPSELL1,
                       TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL2) AS TOUR_UPSELL2,
                       TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL3) AS TOUR_UPSELL3,
                       TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL4) AS TOUR_UPSELL4,
                       TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL5) AS TOUR_UPSELL5,
                       TRIM (OCEAN_FLAG) AS OCEAN_FLAG,
                       V.KIDS_ALONE_CABIN_AGE,
                       V.PAX_MINIMUM_AGE,
                       V.ESC_TWID_MINIMUM_AGE,
                       V.MIN_DRINKING_AGE,
                       V.MIN_GAMBLING_AGE,
                       V.MIN_WAYFIND_AGE,
                       V.MIN_SMOKING_AGE,
                       V.WEB_FEATURED_CRUISE,
                       V.SAILED_FLAG
                  FROM W1 INNER JOIN TVOYLST V ON (W1.VOYAGE_ID = V.VOYAGE_ID)),
            W3
            AS (SELECT W2.*,
                       TRIM (T.TOUR_TITLE) AS TOUR_TITLE,
                       TRIM (T.TOUR_DESC) AS TOUR_DESC,
                       T.TOUR_MINIMUM_AGE,
                       TRIM (T.TOUR_SUB_PRODUCT) AS SUBTRADE_CODE
                  FROM W2 INNER JOIN TTURLST T ON (W2.TOUR_ID = T.TOUR_ID)),
            W4
            AS (SELECT W3.*,
                       TRIM (S.STRING_1) AS ITIN_DESC,
                       TRIM (S.STRING_5) AS TRADE_CODE,
                       TRIM (S.STRING_5) AS ITIN_TRADE_CODE
                  FROM W3
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       TSYSDATA S
                          ON (    S.SYSDATA_TYPE = 'ICT'
                              AND W3.VOY_ITIN_CODE = S.SYSDATA_CODE)),
            W5
            AS (SELECT W4.*,
                       TL.LOCATION_CODE,
                       TL.WEB_DISPLAY_FLAG AS TOUR_WEB_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                       TL.PON_DISPLAY_FLAG AS TOUR_PON_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                       TL.WAITLIST_FLAG AS TOUR_WAITLIST_FLAG,
                       TL.RES_DISPLAY_FLAG AS TOUR_RES_DISPLAY_FLAG
                  FROM W4 INNER JOIN TTURLOC TL ON (W4.TOUR_ID = TL.TOUR_ID)),
            W6
            AS (SELECT W5.*,
                       VL.WEB_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                       VL.PON_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                       VL.EZAIR_FLAG,
                       VL.AIR_AVAL_FLAG,
                       VL.AIR_AVAL_TO_BOOK_DAYS,
                       FULL_ROUTE_DISPLAY_FLAG
                  FROM W5
                       INNER JOIN
                       TVOYLOC VL
                          ON (    W5.VOYAGE_ID = VL.VOYAGE_ID
                              AND VL.LOCATION_CODE = W5.LOCATION_CODE)),
            W7
            AS (SELECT W6.*, SHIP_NAME
                  FROM W6 INNER JOIN TSHIPLST SH ON (W6.SHIP_CODE = SH.SHIP_CODE))
       SELECT *
         FROM W7
        WHERE TRADE_CODE != '';
```

## // Second View

```
    CREATE VIEW WEB_VOY_SEARCH_CRZ_DETAILS_VIEW
AS
   WITH W1
        AS (SELECT TRIM (V.WEB_ITIN_CODE) AS WEB_ITIN_CODE,
                   V.SHIPBOARD_CURRENCY,
                   TRIM (V.VOYAGE_ID) AS VOYAGE_ID,
                   V.VOYAGE_STATUS,
                   V.VOYAGE_ATTR,
                   TRIM (V.PRODUCT_CODE) AS PRODUCT_CODE,
                   V.DURATION,
                   V.DEPARTURE_DATE,
                   V.DEPARTURE_DATE AS CRUISE_START_DATE,
                   V.INCLUDE_EXCLUDE_FLAG,
                   trim (V.FROM_PORT) AS FROM_PORT,
                   trim (V.TO_PORT) AS TO_PORT,
                   V.SHIP_VERSION,
                   V.ZONE_DECK_FLAG,
                   TRIM (V.SHIP_CODE) AS SHIP_CODE,
                   TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL1) AS TOUR_UPSELL1,
                   TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL2) AS TOUR_UPSELL2,
                   TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL3) AS TOUR_UPSELL3,
                   TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL4) AS TOUR_UPSELL4,
                   TRIM (V.TOUR_UPSELL5) AS TOUR_UPSELL5,
                   TRIM (OCEAN_FLAG) AS OCEAN_FLAG,
                   V.KIDS_ALONE_CABIN_AGE,
                   V.PAX_MINIMUM_AGE,
                   V.ESC_TWID_MINIMUM_AGE,
                   V.MIN_DRINKING_AGE,
                   V.MIN_GAMBLING_AGE,
                   V.MIN_WAYFIND_AGE,
                   V.MIN_SMOKING_AGE,
                   V.WEB_FEATURED_CRUISE,
                   V.SAILED_FLAG
              FROM TVOYLST V),
        W2
        AS (SELECT W1.*,
                   CONCAT (RTRIM (S.STRING_1), RTRIM (S.STRING_2))
                      AS ITIN_DESC,
                   TRIM (S.STRING_5) AS TRADE_CODE,
                   TRIM (S.STRING_5) AS ITIN_TRADE_CODE,
                   TRIM (S.STRING_6) AS SUBTRADE_CODE
              FROM W1
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   TSYSDATA S
                      ON (    S.SYSDATA_TYPE = 'ICT'
                          AND W1.WEB_ITIN_CODE = S.SYSDATA_CODE)),
        W3
        AS (SELECT W2.*,
                   VL.LOCATION_CODE,
                   VL.WEB_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                   VL.PON_DISPLAY_FLAG,
                   VL.EZAIR_FLAG,
                   VL.AIR_AVAL_FLAG,
                   VL.AIR_AVAL_TO_BOOK_DAYS,
                   FULL_ROUTE_DISPLAY_FLAG
              FROM W2
                   INNER JOIN TVOYLOC VL
                      ON (W2.VOYAGE_ID = VL.VOYAGE_ID)),
        W4
        AS (SELECT W3.*, SHIP_NAME
              FROM W3
                   INNER JOIN TSHIPLST SH
                      ON (W3.SHIP_CODE = SH.SHIP_CODE))
   SELECT *
     FROM W4
    WHERE TRADE_CODE != '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTEs still have experimental status in H2 and have some known issues. Unfortunately, these names may interact between different views in H2, and `W1` from the first view will conflict with `W1` from the second view. Just give different names for all `WITH` clauses in all views.

The related issue is here:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/910

Comment: I assigned different names for all WITH and it worked, thanks for quick reply.